# Capistrano 3 - best practice for a task which symlinks release path to shared dir

Tags: capistrano, capistrano3

I've been using Capistrano 3 today and am wondering what the best way would be to symlink my release path to my shared directory. This is the opposite way round from what I've done before with Capistrano 2 - it's really because I only have a small set of files versioned in this case, leaving the bulk of the project files unversioned in my shared directory. I think it makes sense in this case to do it this way - any advice otherwise would be welcome if it's likely to be an issue.

I'm also wondering how a symlink like this, pointing latest release path to shared directory, should be handled in cap3? Thanks for any pointers.